# auto-generating substitution in perl

Tags: regex, perl, templates

I'm trying to autogenerate a  regex pattern in perl based on some input, to handle various variables that are created by token pasting in a Makefile...   So, for example, I might have a pattern such as:

```
foo_1_$(AB)_$(CB)
```

Given this pattern, I need to create a regex that will convert all instances of `foo_1_\$(\w+)_\$(\w+)` to `bar_1_\$($1)_\$($2)`.   The main issue I'm having is with the "to" side of the pattern -- I need to increment the `$` number reference each time -- notice that there may be a variable number of tokens in any given pattern.

So...  I'm thinking something like this:

```
foreach $pattern (@patterns) {
    my $from = $pattern;
    # foo_1_$(AB)_$(CD)
    $from =~ s/\$\(\w+\)/\$\(\\w\\\+\)/g;
    # foo_1_$(\w+)_$(\w+)

    my $to = $pattern =~ s/foo/bar/r;
    # bar_1_$(AB)_$(CD);
    $to =~ s/\$\(\w+\)/\\\$\(\$?)/g; #???
    # bar_1_\$($1)_\$($2)
    #           ^      ^

    #this next part is done outside of this loop, but for the example code:
    $line ~= s/\Q$from\E/$to/; 
 }
```

How do I cause each subsequent replacement in my `to` to have an incremental index?

Comment: My suggestion would be to go back to basics and re-approach this as a templating problem. See [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template) or [Mojo::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Template) for example.

Comment: Why do you need to replace `$(AB)` by `\$($1)` which evaluates to `$(AB)`?

Comment: Once generated I need to run this regex on a thousand makefiles...  The variable names in the file where I read the patterns from will not match all of the instances in the makefiles where I have to apply the regex. -- one makefile I might have `foo_1_$(AB)_(CD)`, and `foo_1_$(1)_$(2)` in another.

Comment: Ah... so you mean that given that `..$(AB)..` thing your code should write the regex pattern that ... works on it (or, on the same "kind" of a pattern)?  So what kinds of things can that pattern be?  Just a variable number of `_$(AB)` "tokens" or something completely different?

Comment: These are makefile variables that start with a particular set of prefixes.   The makefile variables do not have a specific format outside of the prefix, but they are all created using token pasting, where the tokens represent various settings the makefile is called with.   But each makefile uses different  variable names for the tokens

Comment: "_specific format outside of the prefix_"  --- so what is that "prefix" -- stuff before the first `_`? Like, `[^_]+_.*` ? Or followed by any number of any subpatterns, but each starting with `_`? Or ...?

Comment: There are plenty of template modules already. Don't (poorly) invent another!

Comment: An actual example of the prefix might be `$(X)LIB_`, where the LIB_ is optional.   The prefix can be described as `\$\(?X\)?(?:_LIB)?(?:_LOCAL)?`   The trick is that not _all_ variables that start with this prefix need to be replaced -- I have to be selective based on the information inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing code to generate regex off of a given pattern is a complex undertaking (except in simplest cases), and that's when it is precisely specified what that pattern can be. In this case I also don't see why one can't solve the problem by writing the regex for a given type of a pattern (instead of writing code that would write regex).<sup>†</sup>

In either case one would need those regex so here's some of that.  Since no precise rules for what the patterns may be are given, I use some basic assumptions drawn from hints in the question.

I take it that the pattern to replace (`foo_`) is followed by a number, and then by the pattern `_$(AB)` (literal dollar and parens with chars inside), repeated any number of times ("*there may be a variable number of tokens*").

One way to approach this is by matching the whole following pattern (all repetitions). With lookahead

```
s/[a-z]+_([0-9]+)(?=_(\$\(\w+\))+)/XXX_$1/;
```

A simple minded test in a one-liner

```
perl -wE'$_=q{foo_1_$(AB)_$(CB)}; s/[a-z]+_([0-9]+)(?=_(\$\(\w+\))+)/XXX_$1/; say'
```

replaces `foo` to `XXX`.  It works for only one group `_$(AB)`, and for more than two,  as well.

This does not match the lone `foo_1`, without following `_$(AB)`, decided based on the "spirit" of the question (since such a requirement is not spelled out). If such a case in fact should be matched as well then that is possible with a few small changes (mostly related to moving `_` into the pattern to be replaced, as optional (`[a-z]+_[0-9]+_?)`)

---

**Update**   If the "tokens" that follow `foo_` (to be replaced) can in fact be *anything* (so not necessarily `$(..)`), except that they are strung together with `_`, then we can use a modification like

```
/[a-z]+_(\d?)(?=(_[^_]+)*)/XXX_$1/;
```

where the number after `foo_` is optional, per example given in a comment. But then it's simpler

```
/[a-z]+(?=(_[^_]+)*)/XXX/;
```

Example

```
perl -wE'
    $_=q{foo_$(AB)_123_$(CD)_foo_$(EF)}; say;
    s/[a-z]+(?=(_[^_]+)*)/XXX/; say'
```

prints

```
foo_$(AB)_123_$(CD)_foo_$(EF)
XXX_$(AB)_123_$(CD)_foo_$(EF)
```

Note: what the above regex does is also done by `/[a-z]+(?=_)/XXX/`.  However, the more detailed regex above can be tweaked and adapted for more precise requirements and I'd use that, or its variations, as a main building block for complete solutions.

If the rules for what may be a pattern are less structured (less than "*any tokens connected with `_`*") then we need to know them, and probably very precisely.

This clearly doesn't generate the regex from a given pattern, as asked, but *is a regex* to match such a (class of) patterns. That can solve the problem given sufficient specification for what those patterns may be like -- which would be necessary for regex generation as well.

---

<sup>†</sup> Another option is that some templating system is used but then you are again directly writing regex to match given types of patterns.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make the assumption that the string is formatted as such.   `foo_$(AB)_123_$(CD)_foo_$(EF)` would also be a valid pattern.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Yeah, I just saw your comment under the question which made me reread the question ... but so what kinds of things are possible?  You have to spell that out _very_ precisely.  One can't have a regex generator that'll work on arbitrary patterns.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry For instance, if you say that the groups following the pattern to be replaced are all `_stuff`  (`_$(AB)` or `_123` ...) then that's a small modification of what I've posted here.  Some other specification may require a big change ... but I can't write to code to generate regex out of anything?

Comment: Essentially I want the first `$(..)` in the variable name to be replaced with `\$($1)`, the second `$(..)` to be replaced with `\$($2)`, etc...

Comment: That's what the question says, I got that -- but why do you want that? Is the objective not to replace what precedes those, and keep those unchanged? Then it's much easier to identify that whole subpattern that follows what need be replaced. If you insist to actually capture and replace `$(...)` one by one, then perhaps split the string or do `while (/.../g)`.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Updated (by adding a section at the end) to my current understanding of what you need.  It doesn't "_generate_" a regex, which would be a very complex undertaking, but it is a regex which should do what is (seems to be) needed

Comment: There are variables such as `foo_2_$(AB)_bar` that I don't want to replace (whereas I might want to replace `foo_2_$(AB)_foobar`, so I need a list of regex's to distinguish between the variables I do want to replace.    I am just replacing the prefix though, so I can indeed group the entire end together.   I will go with a solution based on this answer.   Thanks.